# Injected Bean not instantiated when used in member variable

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, dependency-injection, quarkus

My injected EntityManager is not initiated when used in a member variable. When I use it inside a method, it is initiated.

Is this a problem that has to do with the instantiation time of injected beans in general? Or is it only because I'm using quarkus and hibernate?

```java
    @Inject
    EntityManager entityManager;

    private StudentFacade studentFacade = new StudentFacade(entityManager); //entityManager is null
```

The variable "entityManager" should be initiated, but it has a null value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `studentFacade` is initialized upon constructing whatever object holds the `entityManage`, but whatever framework you use for DI - injects `entityManager` only after object constructing.

So upon initializing of `studentFacade` field - `entityManager` is still null.

To solve this problem you can delay initializing of `studentFacade` variable until after injects. Usually it is accomplished by using some life-cycle hooks, like:

```
@PostConstruct
public void onConstruct() {
    studentFacade = new StudentFacade(entityManager);
}
```

Example is given for Spring framework but I guess almost the same rules applied to whatever you use.

Answer (score 2):

Quarkus also supports constructor injection, so you could also do something like:

```
@Singleton
public class MyBean {

   final StudentFacade studentFacade;

   public MyBean(EntityManager entityManager) {
      this.studentFacade = new StudentFacade(entityManager);
   }

}
```